# How to fix black screen in flutter while Navigating?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, scaffold, flutter-navigation

I am creating a multi-paged app on flutter. When I am using the navigation in it, I am getting a black screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    
    void main() => runApp(MyHomePage());
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Page0(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Page0 extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _Page0State createState() => _Page0State();
    }
    
    class _Page0State extends State<Page0> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF493597),
          body: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 10.0),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 25.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Expense',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 25.0),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'What',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 25.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 60.0),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 10.0,
                  right: 10.0,
                ),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 150,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFFCFCFC),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(75.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(75.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: ListView(
                  primary: false,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 15.0,
                    right: 20.0,
                    top: 25.0,
                  ),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 30.0,
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          //greeting text
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Hello! :)',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'Permanent-Marker',
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 30.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
    
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30.0,
                          ),
    
                          //add button
                          Row(children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(
                                height: 100.0,
                                width: 100.0,
                                child: FittedBox(
                                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                                    elevation: 10.0,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.add,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                       Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewTrip()),);
                                    },
                                  ),``
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
    
                            //add text
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Text(
                                'New trip',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Nanum',
                                  fontSize: 30.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
    
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30.0,
                          ),
    
                          //previous trip button
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 100.0,
                                  width: 100.0,
                                  child: FittedBox(
                                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                                      elevation: 10.0,
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.assessment,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
    
                              //previous trip text
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Previous trips',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Nanum',
                                    fontSize: 30.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
    
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 50.0,
                          ),  
                          
    
                         
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

And the NewTrip widget is as follows

```
class NewTrip extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(      
              body: Text('NEW TRIP'),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

The home page is loading fine but as soon as I click the new trip button, it shows a black screen. Probably there is an issue with MaterialApp or Scaffold but I am not able to fix it yet. Can anyone tell me what's the problem and how to fix it?

**Updated the full code as requested in the comments.**

Comment: on physical device? or simulator?

Comment: On physical device

Comment: The codes that are provided in the question are too minimal... It may be from NewTrip's `build` method, But it's not clear!

Comment: Please provide more code from relevant widgets. Would be happy to help :)

Comment: I've updated with the full code.

Comment: Remove `MaterialApp` from `NewTrip` and test again

Comment: No..not working

Comment: please check the recent answer

Comment: Do it fulfil your requirement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay so after some research on the internet, I found out that it's the FloatingActionButton that is causing the trouble.

I replaced the **FloatingActionButton** with **MaterialButton** and this fixed my issue.

Comment: If you still want to use floating button, add the property of floating button called "herotag". This works for me. 

Comment: Yes that is the problem, FloatingActionButton is a hero widget with a default hero tag, you are using 2 floatingActionButtons in your screen without explicitly giving them a heroTag. By doing so, Flutter cannot tell which hero to move forward to next screen, as there are 2 hero widget with same tag. So, add a unique heroTag to both of you FloatingActionButtons like this to your FloatingActionButton.

Comment: Also, remove your MaterialApp, there is no point of using 2 material Apps in one flutter app.

Comment: Also, Please accept your answer as correct one, so others don't try to answer it.

Answer (score 23):

So in `NewTrip()` remove `MaterialApp` since it inherits from the parent. Just return `Scaffold`.

```
class NewTrip extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(      
       body: Text('NEW TRIP'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Before:**

[image]

```
class NewTrip extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Text('NEW TRIP'),
    );
  }
}
```

So to Solve this problem we wrap the new navigate widget with `scaffold` widget

### **Solution After:**

[image]

```
class NewTrip extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Material(
        child: Text('NEW TRIP'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Please check the full code edit from your code. Actually you are using two FloatingActionButton. So you need to use two heroTag with different name. I already added in the code. No problem with NewTrip class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Page0(),
    );
  }
}

class Page0 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page0State createState() => _Page0State();
}

class _Page0State extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF493597),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 10.0),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 25.0,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Expense',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'What',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 60.0),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 10.0,
              right: 10.0,
            ),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 150,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFFCFCFC),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(75.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(75.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: ListView(
              primary: false,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 15.0,
                right: 20.0,
                top: 25.0,
              ),
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 30.0,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      //greeting text
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'Hello! :)',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Permanent-Marker',
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 30.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),

                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30.0,
                      ),

                      //add button
                      Row(children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Container(
                            height: 100.0,
                            width: 100.0,
                            child: FittedBox(
                              child: FloatingActionButton(
                                heroTag: "btn",
                                elevation: 10.0,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.add,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => NewTrip()),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                        //add text
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Text(
                            'New trip',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Nanum',
                              fontSize: 30.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),

                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30.0,
                      ),

                      //previous trip button
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 100.0,
                              width: 100.0,
                              child: FittedBox(
                                child: FloatingActionButton(
                                  heroTag: "btn1",
                                  elevation: 10.0,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.assessment,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          //previous trip text
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: Text(
                              'Previous trips',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Nanum',
                                fontSize: 30.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),

                      SizedBox(
                        height: 50.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

NewTrip class

```
class NewTrip extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('NEW TRIP'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are using a [materialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) inside another [materialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html)

Navigator just changes the pages and we don't need separate materialApp in NewTrip().

So the NewTrip should be as follow

```
class NewTrip extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('NEW TRIP'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe there can only be one `MaterialApp` Widget in the entire Flutter application because MaterialApp Widget is likely to be the main or core component of Flutter. So when you try to navigate to a new screen try returning Scaffold Widget instead of `MaterialApp` Widget.

```
class NewTrip extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(      
                  body: Text('NEW TRIP'),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**ThemeData**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html), along with the parameter **[scaffoldBackgroundColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/scaffoldBackgroundColor.html)**.
For example:

```
ThemeData (
   scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it is caused by:

```
// to set portait screen orientation 
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientation([
   DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
   DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
]);
// Instead i use `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` on my AndroidManifest.xml.
```

That I declared when the page widget render. Removed it solve my black screen issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change [scaffoldBackgroundColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/scaffoldBackgroundColor.html)

```
theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,  //here
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),

class NewTrip extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('NEW TRIP'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply just put scaffold in next page that's it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the page you navigate does not contain Scaffold the page will be black since **Scaffold** Implements the basic material design visual layout structure  so apply Scaffold and the parent widget material app.

Comment: This is not true, you can not use a scaffold in flutter without getting this black screen issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing because the widget you are navigating does not have any material widget.

Just wrap the navigated screen's return widget with `Scaffold` as a parent.